# How to release returned object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, nsmutabledictionary

I have coded this method in a class:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)fetch {
   NSMutableDictionary *ret = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

  // filling ret with some data here

  return ret;
}
```

Is the way of returning this NSMUtableDictionary object without release correct ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: Little hint: the next iOS Version has features so you don't have to manage memory anymore yourself. ;-)

Comment: Just use `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` instead as it is already autoreleased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)fetch {
   NSMutableDictionary *ret = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      // filling ret with some data here
   return [ret autorelease];
}
```

To learn more about `autorelease`ing, read [this Apple document called Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

Answer (score 2):

use like this

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)fetch {
   NSMutableDictionary *ret = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

  // filling ret with some data here

  return [ret autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Developer Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

Auto release puts the object into a autorelease pool and release is called later after it has been returned.